# Uploading file with

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to upload a file to location ~/Files however I am not successful.

I use MVC 3 and my code is thus.

I have a controller GetFileController

I have an action method in this controller

Comment: You are making a post request. Send your id value with Html.Hidden() helper method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post your id field with a hidden input, as :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetFiles", "GetFile", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input name ="id" type="hidden" value="1"/>
    <label for="file">Upload Image:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" />
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetFiles(int id, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        // file stream logic
    }
```

Comment: Forgot to add [HttpPost] attribute. Could you please try again?

Comment: I had that added no luck still.

Comment: Show your get method code that takes id as parameter.(First request)

Comment: I am going to be using this: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/ ... thanks for help though. :)

Answer (score 1):

> I have an action method in this controller

If this is the only action method in your controller then you'll receive this error. Add a `GET` Action Method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetFiles()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: He is posting a file stram. How can he access posted file with get request?

Comment: Efe, could you explain further please on Html.Hidden() for this particular situation? I do have an actionresult for getFiles where I am passing the ID

Comment: @EfeKaptan the initial `GET` request for the page is where he is having the issue.